# Disabling or forcing a cipher suite when using SSL in OpenFlow

Tags: ssl, openflow, openvswitch

I have a simple SDN setup where a switch (using Open vSwitch) and a controller (using OpenFlow controller) communicate with SSL. I would like to inspect the traffic via Wireshark.

I found out that the SSL session is using Diffie-Hellman key exchange (cipher suite `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`), and therefore Wireshark cannot decrypt the traffic. Is there any way to disable Diffie-Hellman key exchange (or any cipher suite) in OpenFlow, or to force to use a specific cipher suite?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you defined the connection to the controller in OVS? If it's similar like [this](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/SSL-on-Open-vSwitch-and-ovs-controller) tutorial here, just leave out all the SSL stuff. Plaintext is default.

Comment: I need to use SSL in my experiment. And yes, I followed that tutorial.